# Problem with merging feature branch on develop branch

Tags: github, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict, git-fetch

I have questions about git merging. I'm a student, and currently working on a project with four colleagues. So, I tried to merge my feature branch on develop branch, and got some conflicts that i didn't know how to solve.

Because i didn't have time i just did git merge --abort command. After that command i got message: fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'. So i was googling and found somewhere to do a command that deletes index file(i guess?) rm -f .git/index and it deleted ALL files from our project. Found on google to do: git fetch -all and git reset --hard origin/develop. And after i did that, i got my files back and merge stopped, but files from feature branch stayed on my local develop. And after i tried to checkout to feature branch i got this response: the following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout. So i didn't know if it's safe to delete them from local develop and just did git checkout -f featurebranch because i needed those new features for college that day. Can someone please help me and give me advice, what should i do? Can i delete those files on local develop and merge feature branch again?